# index out of range in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, indexoutofrangeexception

I wrote a program that gets the name, family and age of student, saves them in the database and shows them in `DataGridView`. I can see added student after adding it in `DatagridView` but I can't click it. Error is index out of range (index -1 does not have value)

```cs
private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string name = txtName.Text;
        string family = txtFamily.Text;
        int age = int.Parse(txtAge.Text);
        foreach (var item in Database.tbl_student)
        {
            if (item.Name.Trim().ToLower().Equals(name.Trim().ToLower())
                        && item.Family.Trim().ToLower().Equals(family.Trim().ToLower()))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("this student is duplicate..");
                return;
            }
        }
        Database.tbl_student.Add(new Student() { Name = name, Family = family, Age = age });
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = Database.tbl_student;
    } catch(Exception error)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Index -1 means there is no columns in the DGV.  What this means is when the application starts and event is occurring before the DGV is constructed.  The error is easily fixed by putting a IF statement in the Click event and return if the number of rows in the DGV is less than zero.

Comment: You should post how `Database` and `tbl_student` are defined. If `Database` is a “static” Class and it has a “static” property of `List<Student>` called `tbl_student` … ? … then the code works without errors. I am just not getting “when” this index out range error is thrown as it does not appear to be coming from the posted code. Is it possible the grid may have some other events wired up? Like a `CellClick` or `CellContentClick` events?